# When building an OpenCV project on iOS, why is CvStereoBMState undeclared?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opencv, disparity-mapping

I am working on an iOS project using OpenCV. I am trying to create disparity map of an image. While implementing this, Xcode is showing `CvStereoBMState` as being an undeclared identifier.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs: CvStereoBMState is the old C-Style, which seems to be unsupported, but you can now use the new C++ interface.

For further information take a look at [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction - StereoBM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereobm).